# Learning Clojure by reading core.clj

Tags: clojure

I came across the tweet today:

> Start each day by reading the implementation of a function or macro in Clojure's core.clj.

My Clojure knowledge is really basic, I can hardly read other's Clojure (or Lisp) code.
Can I do well with [`core.clj`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj), especially I have the feeling it is full of complicated macros?

Comment: just. do. it.  My favorite thing about clojure is that the density of the code and functional style means I can read every line of everything I use and understand it in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think a better place to start is by doing a project; anything that interests you and seems manageable is good.

`core.clj` is not readable right now; perhaps the latter half is, but the first half isn't something I'd wish on anyone as an introduction to the language. The truth is, even if you read it very carefully, you'd not have a solid idea of what was going on without also reading a lot of Java code, too.

- Make an asynchronous text-based game (technomancy—Phil Hagelburg—has a nice one to look through on his Github, though it's a little dated by now)
- Scrape websites using the *Enlive* library.
- Maybe just solve some math problems, and/or
- Graph things using *Incanter*.

Build first. Once you acquaint yourself with the tools you are using, start reading them. The libraries mentioned here are well written (you can't go wrong with anything by Christophe Grand, for instance), and **once you start using them, you'll understand *what* they do, which makes it much simpler to figure out the *why* and *how* later.**

Answer (score 8):

That tweet is probably a great idea once you have enough experience to be able to read Clojure code well enough to understand what is going on.

Before that point, I'd recommend gaining a strong familiarity with the language by writing a lot of small mini-programs. It's best to learn by doing, after all.

I personally found [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) very useful while I was learning Clojure.

Comment: Project Euler was a fun way to learn the very basics of Clojure and some of contrib, and I'd say its one of the best first steps if you have even a little Mathematical knowledge. I'd encourage moving on from it ASAP, though, as there are diminishing returns in learning a language by solving PE.

Answer (score 4):

You might also take a look at the [Clojure Koans](http://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans), though they may be a bit beginner-oriented for you, depending on how much Clojure you already know.

Answer (score 3):

As a good starting point, I would recommend [4Clojure](http://www.4clojure.com/). It looks similar to Project Euler and Code Katas, but has more forgiving learning curve.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot I don't understand in it, but there's also a lot I do, and it's fascinating looking at the language getting bootstrapped from its minimal initial implementation.

Comment: Yes. Understanding the bootstrapping is a nice excercise. But nothing for beginners. Especially since core is highly not-representative clojure code. Exactly because of the bootstrapping. I would rather read some fine project as an excercise.

Answer (score 2):

Another place to look for little projects to get you going would be any of the Kata repos.  My personal favorite at this point is [Coding Kata.org](http://codingkata.org/), but there's also [Coding Dojo](http://codingdojo.org/), [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/) (with a little translation effort), and of course [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=code+kata).

Try to do one of those a day and you'll quickly pick up the language.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the Clojure [contrib](https://github.com/clojure/clojure-contrib) libraries or look at some Clojure projects on github to get a better feel for idiomatic Clojure code.

Answer (score 0):

The advice above is good. Another fine example of learning-by-doing is well illustrated here by the creator of Ruby on Rails: [How Do I Learn to Program?](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2582-how-do-i-learn-to-program) I hope you have an app that you care about that you could just go for in Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

I find the clojure.core a good way to find ideas of how things are implemented, as more of a reference guide.  As noted earlier, the early parts or neither pretty nor exemplary.  However, the later parts can be a good example especially when needing to write a function that is close to core function but different.